# Basic Auth para autenticar webservice soap - PHP

Tags: php, web-service, soap

estou tendo um problema com autenticação quando vou tentar consumir um web service soap.
Ao entrar com a url no browser, é apresentada u dailog pedindo usuario e senha.
Porem eu preciso fazer essa autenticação sem que esse dialog seja apresentado, ou seja autenticação toda no back-end.
tentei passar o login e senha pelo SoapHeader mas sem sucesso.
Segue o script:

```
!IMPORTANT: O tipo de autenticação é (Basic auth)    

$credenciais = self::fncGeraAuth();   
//array que contem user e senha para autenticação    
//Array ( [UserName] => xxxxx [Password] => xxxxx) 

$_rCliente2 = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("encoding" => "ISO-8859-1"));  

$Header = new SoapHeader($wsdl,'Authorization', $credenciais, false);

$_rCliente2->__setSoapHeaders($Header);

$result = $_rCliente2->fncRecuperaPapel($Instituição);
//tentado acessar uma função do webservice passando um parametro 

var_dump($result);
exit();

Erro:
SoapFault: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '
...........?wsdl' : failed to load external entity ".........wsdl"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde!

Fiz um teste rápido localmente, com um serviço **wsdl** feito em PHP, utilizando Basic Auth HTTP.

Consegui fazer a autenticação passando o login e senha diretamente no **SoapClient**.

```php
$client = new SoapClient('http://teste-soap.local/server.php?wsdl',['trace'=>1,'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'login' => 'adriano', 'password' => 'maciel']);
```

Também tentei utilizar o **SoapHeader**, porém esse não funciona neste caso, pois a autenticação deve ser feita ao instanciar o client.

Comment: ainda estou tendo o mesmo erro...o item 'login' e 'password' é padrão para Basic Auth ou você pode definir isso com outro nome?

Comment: Você pode passar qualquer chave e valor, no caso eu espero no servidor a autenticação padrão. Montei usando: $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];  e $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

Os campos que você vai passar, dependem do servidor que você está autenticando.

Comment: veja como eu montei

$_rCliente2 = new SoapClient($_uWS, array ("encoding" => "UTF-8", "cache_wsdl"=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE, "Username" =>  $credenciais[Username], "Password" => $credenciais[Username]));

no meu caso o web service foi escrito em java embora acredito que isso não interfira.

Comment: Obrigado Adriano...sua resposta funcionou para meu problema!
acontece que o para Basic Auth deve-se usar "login" para o username e "password" para a senha, seguindo este padrão a autenticação seguirá com sucesso !
Obrigado e sucesso para você !!